# Throwing out cake or pastry larger than a k'zayis

Tags: sources-mekorot, bread, bal-tashchit-waste

One is not allowed to throw out pieces of bread larger than a k'zayis.  Rabbi Doniel Neustadt ([here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5766-behaaloscha/) in footnote 2) says this also applies to pastry and cake, but doesn't provide a source for this.  Does anyone know of a source for this, or if anyone argues?   Thanks.